# Printing/console logging from map object

Tags: javascript, object, oop

Lets say I have `personalRecords` parameter.. and it accepts this map object:

```
new Map([['100', 9.58], ['200', 19.19]])
```

I want to take these numbers and print them out / console.log in VSCode in such format:

100m: 9.58s

200m: 19.19s

I can't seem to figure out how to take these numbers out of the object and print them out properly. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Once you have a Map, you can iterate over the entries using `for(const entry of mapV)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for each to achieve that

```js
const personalRecord = new Map([['100', 9.58], ['200', 19.19]])

for(let record of personalRecord){ 
  console.log(record[0] + "m: " + record[1] + "s")
}
```